# How to deploy my .pkl machine learnt model made with fastai on my other machine with python on the desktop

Tags: python, machine-learning, fast-ai

I have followed the [fastai](https://www.fast.ai/) documentation and the videos on how to create a ML model that can detect the different home care products like soaps and deodorants and so on.
I have now come to where I have the model that supposedly works with an error rate of 0.03...
to my understanding its about a 97% accurate model, however I have no idea on how to predict on other images on another machine. I have exported it using the "learn.export('Home_Care_Model.pkl')" as said in the documentation, with no luck.

Now in the documentation is states that I would need to define the model again with a classes and training set and so on again but now I'm on another computer so i don't have those files on it and I can't go through running it on the web as it is supposed to be run as a python script on any desktop (end goal).

What I'm going towards is where I have one file with unsorted images that then when i run the model on will separate the images into two different folders according to the prediction.

I have been searching for an answer to this and to be honest i'm not sure if i am just not understanding it well enough or something as i have come up empty with every attempt i make to get this model working.

Here is my training code:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
%matplotlib inline
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import os


os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'


path = Path('my files path...')
print(path)


for folder in ('soap','deo'): # I have more but it will waist space.
print (folder)
verify_images(path/folder, max_size=500)
np.random.seed(42)


data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train='.', valid_pct=0.3, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), 
size=224, num_workers=4).normalize(imagenet_stats)


data.classes


from fastai.metrics import error_rate
learn= create_cnn(data, models.resnet34, metrics=error_rate)


learn


defaults.device = torch.device('cuda')
learn.fit_one_cycle(5)


learn.unfreeze()


learn.lr_find()


learn.recorder.plot()


learn.fit_one_cycle(4, max_lr=slice(3e-6,3e-5))


learn.save('day2Test_02')


from fastai.widgets import *


ds, idxs = DatasetFormatter().from_toplosses(learn)


ImageCleaner(ds, idxs, path)


df = pd.read_csv(path/'cleaned.csv', header='infer')
df.head()


df[(df['name'].apply(lambda x: len(x)<5))]


np.random.seed(42)
db =(ImageList.from_df(df,path).random_split_by_pct(0.2).label_from_df().transform(get_transforms(), size= 224).databunch(bs=8)).normalize(imagenet_stats)


data.classes, data.c, len(data.train_ds), len(data.valid_ds)


db.classes, db.c,len(db.train_ds), len(data.valid_ds)


learn.data = db


learn.freeze()

learn.fit_one_cycle(4)


learn.save('day2Test_02_01')


learn.unfreeze()


learn.lr_find()


learn.recorder.plot()


learn.fit_one_cycle(4, max_lr=slice(3e-5,3e-4))


learn.save('dat2Test_test2')


interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)


interp.plot_confusion_matrix()


learn.export('day2Test_test2.pkl')
```

Comment: were you able to deploy the model? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: no not yet work has caught up to me and i have had to put this on the back burner :(